# Check if user likes assigned app page without user presence

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

I would like to give users of my app who like my assigned app page a special daily virtual bonus. Therefor i do a daily lookup to check if a user likes my page, it can be done like so:

`https://graph.facebook.com/FBID/likes/PAGE_ID`

It works with about 30% of the users who have set their likes to public. For the rest i need an access_token.
Does it have to be a *user* access_token or could an *app* access_token have those permissions too (since it's an assigned app page, as newly required by FB)?

I want to check if the user likes my page even if the user doesn't use my app that day, therefor i want to avoid to use the signed request (doesn't contain the like info of for an assigned app page) or the `/me/likes/PAGE_ID/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a user access token with the `user_likes` and `offline_access` permissions granted to it.

Comment: i was affraid it would be like that...users don't like to give away offline_access...so i'll have to stick with the solution and check their like when they come online.

Comment: Also offline access permission is being deprecated, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/

Answer (score 0):

Hav you tried the Graph-Explorer?
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

But I think you need a user-Token.